# Input acepte solo tres dígitos y contabilice los ceros en la base de datos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Al momento de ingresar 001 que salga la cifra completa no solo 1 en la base de datos.

```html
<div class="col-md-1 col-lg-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"># Contratista</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nCont" id="nCont" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estimado, si realmente necesitas resolver este problema lee este artículo primero, luego vuelves y vemos como va la ayuda. Saludos. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Falta información en tu pregunta para poder saber de que hablas pero por lo que entiendo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Utiliza la API de HTML5 para que el input solo acepte números y después que el máximo número de dígitos sean 3: **maxlength="3"** De igual forma con JS al pasar a base de datos verificar el lentgh y pasar sólo 3 dígitos.

Si utilizas ZEROFILL con un length de 3 o lo que necesites puede funcionar en tu base de datos pero no se como estés guardando los datos.